# Qt - Is there a signal for each lost focus on QSpinBox just when the value changes?

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

I need to capture whole changed value just when the widget loses focus.

I know I have valueChanged() and editingFinished() signals. The problem with valueChanged() signal is that it will be fired for each pressed key and the problem with editingFinished() is that it is fired even when his value don't change.

The question is: Is possible to have a signal fired for each lost focus **just** when the value changes?

If don't, comes a new question: Is there a way to get the widget's old value inside a slot connected at editingFinished() for comparison against current value and decision if the value change occurred?

Comment: Why don`t you inherit QSpinBox and implement this logic in that subclass?

Comment: What prevents you from caching the old value and compare it with the new one to see whether it is changed or not?

Comment: dvvrd, I'll do that. Tks.

Comment: vahancho, I'll merge you suggestion with dvvrd's suggestion. Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try extend the QSpinBox and then reimplement focusOutEvent() 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#focusOutEvent

Comment: Tks Kamil. I'll get all these tips and resolve my problem. Tks.